# Unable to receive full wallet with Google play service v8.4.0 and build tool 23.0.2

Tags: google-play-services, android-pay

I referred to the tutorial on Android Pay on site
 [Androi Pay integration tutorial](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial)
 and able to execute it and get the full wallet. This Biker app is compiled with build tool v22.0.1 and Google play services library v8.1.0. But my application requires build tool version 23.0.2 and Google play service library v8.4.0. Full wallet is not received in the Biker application when I do these two modifications to build.gradle:

1. Build tool from v22.0.1 to 23.0.2
2. Google play service wallet library from v8.1.0 to v8.4.0

I get result code 1 on activity result when the full wallet is requested.

Also 'Change card/address' button on the wallet fragment fails to respond with these modifications in build.gradle. I have updated the Android SDK. Is there anything I am missing?

**Edit 02/16/2016**

Now I referred the latest Android Pay source from [Github](https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart) that has latest build tool (v23.0.2) and Google Play services library (v8.4.0). I can't run the application in Android Pay mode as I don't have cards that are supported by Android Pay. I did not find any workaround for introducing mock cards in Android Pay to work with Wallet mode ENVIRONMENT_TEST

After modifying the `WalletFragmentStyle` to

```
WalletFragmentStyle walletFragmentStyle = new WalletFragmentStyle()
            .setBuyButtonText(BuyButtonText.BUY_WITH_GOOGLE)
            .setBuyButtonAppearance(BuyButtonAppearance.CLASSIC)
            .setBuyButtonWidth(Dimension.MATCH_PARENT);
```

I get the same response in onActivityResult with RESPONSE CODE as 1 when requesting for Full wallet. The error number is 10. I am unable to trace what error 10 corresponds to.

Comment: Please post your logcat error message.

Comment: I am using the app in sandbox mode. There are no logcat errors. Just that the WalletFragment is not providing status RESULT_OK when asking for Full Wallet.

Comment: Hi @Kulai were you able to find a solution to this error code 10?

Comment: Updated to Google Play services library 9.0.0 and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You  need to click '**Install repository and sync project**' after encountering the error. This issue will be fixed after installing all the latest versions of build tools and other updates.

Comment: I have installed latest build tool version 23.0.2 and Google play service 8.4.0

Comment: Hi @Kulai were you able to find a solution? Error code 10?